# Troubles WebIOPi get values from sensor DS18B20 without modify config file

Tags: ds18b20, webiopi

I have a question, I'm working in a project where are a necessary getting of values from a DS18B20 I had read this posts from WebIOPi forum:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/webiopi/KPOGcDwAODE/zSu9rMR4YpUJ

and

http://webiopi.trouch.com/Tutorial_Devices.html

If I remove the # to a sensor name from the config file and refresh the web page crashes and I don't know  what's the cause and how can I fix it?

Hence, I'm trying to do it as you write above without modify the config file, so this is my code...

script.py

```
import webiopi
from webiopi.devices.sensor.onewiretemp import DS18B20

GPIO=webiopi.GPIO

Temp0=DS18B20
TEMP=4

CONTROL=25
LEFTROT=24
RIGHTROT=23

varTemp=0

@webiopi.macro
def getTemp():
        varTemp="%.2f%" %(Temp0.getCelsius())
        varTemp="Hello"
        return varTemp

@webiopi.macro
def openGreenhouse():
    GPIO.digitalWrite(RIGHTROT,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.digitalWrite(LEFTROT,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.digitalWrite(CONTROL,GPIO.HIGH)
    webiopi.sleep(4)
    GPIO.digitalWrite(CONTROL,GPIO.LOW)


@webiopi.macro
def closeGreenhouse():
    GPIO.digitalWrite(RIGHTROT,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.digitalWrite(LEFTROT,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.digitalWrite(CONTROL,GPIO.HIGH)
    webiopi.sleep(4)
    GPIO.digitalWrite(CONTROL,GPIO.LOW)


def setup():
    GPIO.setFunction(CONTROL,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setFunction(LEFTROT,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setFunction(RIGHTROT,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setFunction(TEMP,GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.digitalWrite(CONTROL,GPIO.LOW)

def loop():
        webiopi.sleep(1)


def destroy():
    GPIO.digitalWrite(CONTROL,GPIO.LOW)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test Button GPIO |18 Enero Carlos Hdz</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    webiopi().ready(function() {

    var flag=true;

    var openGreenHouseButton=webiopi().createButton("openGhButton","Open",function(){
        if(flag===true){
            document.getElementById("openGhButton").innerHTML="Close";
            flag=false;
            webiopi().callMacro("openGreenhouse");

        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("openGhButton").innerHTML="Open";
            flag=true;
            webiopi().callMacro("closeGreenhouse");
        }
    });

    setInterval(callMacro_getTemp,5000);

    $("#controls").append(openGreenHouseButton);


    });

    function callMacro_getTemp(){
       webiopi().callMacro("getTemp",[],getTempCallback);
    }

    function getTempCallback(macro,args,data){
      $("#pTemp").text("hola" + ".");
    }   

    webiopi().refreshGPIO(true);

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        button {
            display: block;
            margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            width: 160px;
            height: 120px;
            font-size: 24pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: White;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p align="center">Control of Automatic Greenhouse</p>
    <div id="controls" align="center"></div>
    <div align="center" style="color:#0000FF">
     Temperature: <p id="pTemp"></p>
     Level of Water: <input type="text"/><br/>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the value of the temperature didn't show. I guess is the part of the callback of macros but I don't have idea what to do yet?

May I ask for help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!!

I reconnected everything and made a search where I found that  the last update of Raspbian changed the device tree and you have to enable it so:

1.- Modify the /boot/config.txt in your RPi.

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=<4>
```

2.-Enable I2C, SPI and Device Tree.

```
raspi-config
```

3.- Command these:

```
modprobe w1-gpio

modprobe w1-therm
cd /sys/bus/w1/devices
ls
//you have to see more than one sentence (we select a slave omit the master setence, for example:)
cd 28-01157362d7ff
cat w1-slave
```

So next we need to change the config file of WebIOPi:

```
sudo /etc/webiopi/config
```

and enable:

```
temp3=DS18B20 slave: 28-01157362d7ff
```

And that's it, solved :D